# Need help breaking down code to smaller parts C

Tags: c

I'm pretty new to C so be gentle, somewhy my code doesn't work, be kind and help my figure it out why it doesn't, also if it's possible to make it shorter without making it too complicated, please help in that too.

```
 main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "swap.h"
#include "magic.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i,j,count;
    int min=atoi(argv[1]);
    int max=atoi(argv[2]);

    if(min>max)
    {
        swap(&min, &max);
    }

    if (min<0)
    {
        min=1;
    }

    if(argc<2 || argc>5){exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
    else
    {
       magic();
    }

}
```

Magic.c

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include magic.h

magic(char *argv[])
{
    for(i = min; i<=max; i++)
    {

        count = 0;

        for(j=2; j<=i/2; j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(count==0 && i!= 1 && i!= 0)
            printf("%d \n",i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But you didn't tell us what it *should* do and what the current output is.

Comment: Above comment + How does magic get min and max? What does code doesn't work mean?

Comment: `min` and `max` pass to  `magic` as arguments.

Comment: you call magic without args in main.c

Comment: `if(argc<2 || argc>5)` should be `if(argc<3 || argc>5)` if you are using `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`, and the line should be placed before you actually reference `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`.

Comment: your include statement on line 3 of main.c is missing quotes

Comment: if `max < 0` then this`if (min<0) min=1;` can leave `max < min`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is as single file for simplicity

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int *a,int *b){
    int c=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=c;
}

void magic(int min, int max);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int min,max;

    if(argc!=3) // (argc<2 || argc>5)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    min=atoi(argv[1]);
    max=atoi(argv[2]);

    if(min>max)
        swap(&min, &max);

    if (min<0)
        min=1;

    magic(min,max);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


void magic(int min, int max){
    int i,j,count;

    for(i = min; i<=max; i++){
        count = 0;

        for(j=2; j<=i/2; j++) {

            if(i%j==0){
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(count==0 && i!= 1 && i!= 0)
            printf("%d \n",i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some error in your code :

you are trying to use the variables `min`, `max` and `count`in your function `magic` however since they are declared in your `main` function `magic` does not have knowledge of them.

you should change your `main` function like :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "swap.h"
#include "magic.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int min=atoi(argv[1]);
    int max=atoi(argv[2]);

    if(min>max)
    {
        swap(&min, &max);
    }

    if (min<0)
    {
        min=1;
    }

    if(argc<2 || argc>5){exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
    else
    {
        magic(min, max);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and your `magic` function :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "magic.h"

int magic(int min, int max)
{
    int count;
    for(int i = min; i<=max; i++)
    {
        count = 0;

         for(int j=2; j<=i/2; j++)
         {
             if(i%j==0)
             {
                 count++;
                 break;
             }
          }

          if(count==0 && i!= 1 && i!= 0)
              printf("%d \n",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the `main` function I change `magic();` by `magic(min, max);` to pass parameters to the function which can be retrieve in `magic` with it's new signature `int magic(int min, int max)`.

Since your `magic` function return an integer don't forget to specify the return value in the signature of your function.